# Excel file generated with C # is corrupted (ExcelExportEngine & IExportEngine)

Tags: c#, excel, export-to-excel

I have an application made in C # that allows to generate an excel file from a list (List <>).

The code that generates the excel file has worked without problems but today a user who still uses windows 7 has indicated that the excel file has been generated but when it is opened it is unreadable.

The code to generate the excel is as follows:

```js
IExportEngine engine = new ExcelExportEngine();
engine.AddData(productListExport);
MemoryStream memory = engine.Export();
FileStream fileStream;

SaveFileDialog saveFileDialog1 = new SaveFileDialog();
saveFileDialog1.Filter = "Excel files (*.xls or .xlsx)|.xls;*.xlsx";
saveFileDialog1.Title = "Export product list to Excel";
saveFileDialog1.ShowDialog();
                
if (saveFileDialog1.FileName != "")
{
 String path = Path.GetFullPath(saveFileDialog1.FileName);
 fileStream = new FileStream(path, FileMode.OpenOrCreate,  FileAccess.Write, FileShare.ReadWrite);
 memory.WriteTo(fileStream);
 fileStream.Close();
}
```

When you open the excel file, a message appears saying that the format and extension does not match, if you choose to open the option to open anyway, it looks like the following image:

[image]

Any suggestions or comments are welcome.

UPDATE:

About ExcelExportEngine:

https://github.com/vvenegasv/exportable

Comment: you should encapsulate your streams in using-statements

Comment: What is `ExcelExportEngine` and what format does it produce? There's no point in using eg `xlsx` when the generated binary is `xls` or vice versa. Actually, there's no point in using the obsolete `xls` format in the first place. It was replaced by `xlsx` 13 years ago

Comment: From the reference to `docProps.xml` this must be an `xlsx` file. `xlsx` is a zip package containing XML files. If the file is corrupt, a simple test using *any* compression utility will find the problem. Did the user save the file as `xls`  instead of `xlsx`?

Comment: If you save an `xlsx` file with the `xls` extension you *will* get a warning saying the formats don't match but Excel may still be able to open the file. You should *remove* the `*.xls` option altogether and ensure the file is saved with an `xlsx` extension no matter what the user enters

Comment: @PanagiotisKanavos how do you know that "_If you save an xlsx file with the xls extension you will get a warning saying the formats don't match[...]_"? This is an abitrary piece of C# code. As you pointed out in the first comment we don't even know what `ExcelExportEngine` is.

Comment: @MarkusDeibel because I tried it - Excel would either silently load the file or complain. And no, it's not arbitrary - the contents look like an `xlsx` file and the code itself asks for the filename *and extension* after exporting.

Comment: This is definitely an xlsx file because it starts with "PK". XLSX files (and all other MSOffice `.???x` files) are actually just zip files, you can rename them as `.zip` and open them up.

Comment: The user generates it as xls, if you generate it as xlsx it is created without problem and opens without problems (in windows 10)

ExcelEsportEngine is:
https://pbs.twimg.com/media/EGW21tuWkAArU4Z?format=png&name=medium

Comment: @FabiánRomo this code doesn't specify a format, it generates an `xlsx` file. The code allows the user to save the file using the wrong extension. As for what ExcelExportEngine is, I was asking about the library itself. I found it through googling though.

Comment: At this moment I generate a file with another extension, for example file.gpt and the excel created is file.gpr.xls and it opens without problems and there is no error in the file.

Comment: @FabiánRomo any reason you don't just use `Export(path)` and get rid of the extra code?

Answer (score 2):

The screenshot looks like the contents of an `xlsx` file. An `xlsx` file is a zip package containing XML files. The various xml paths in there are a very strong indication. The `PK` bytes too, but I saw `docProps.xml` first.

The code itself has a serious problem - it generates the Excel file contents *before* asking for a format. Given that the `xls` format became obsolete 13 years ago, the only sensible default is to use `xlsx`. If an `xlsx` file is saved as `xls`, Excel will complain. In my case though, it was able to load the file.

It looks like the code uses the [Exportable](https://github.com/vvenegasv/exportable) package. The examples in the Github repo show how to specify the format. Apart from `MemoryStream Export()` though, the library also has an [Export(string path)](https://github.com/vvenegasv/exportable/blob/master/src/Exportable/Engines/Excel/ExcelExportEngine.cs#L128) that writes to a file. The source code shows that `Export(string)` selects the format based on the extension and throws if it's invalid.

This means that the code can be reduced to :

```
IExportEngine engine = new ExcelExportEngine();
engine.AddData(productListExport);

var saveFileDialog1 = new SaveFileDialog(){
    Filter = "Excel files (*.xls or .xlsx)|.xls;*.xlsx",
    Title = "Export product list to Excel"
}
saveFileDialog1.ShowDialog();

if (saveFileDialog1.FileName != "")
{
    var path = Path.GetFullPath(saveFileDialog1.FileName);
    engine.Export(path);
}
```

I'd also suggest getting rid of the `xls` option too. It's not just that it was replaced 13 years ago. The format wasn't well defined to begin so libraries always have issues producing the same output Excel did. Services like Google Sheets or Office Online only work with `xlsx`. You have to *pay* to get `xls` support. The file size is a lot smaller too.

Comment: "The screenshot looks like the contents of an xlsx file" It is because the user sent me the generated excel by mail and opened it on my PC with Office 2010 (WIN 10), but what I visualize, he also sees it when he opens it from his Windows 7 PC.

Comment: @FabiánRomo as I already explained, the `xls` extension was wrong to begin with. Modify the code to only accept `xlsx` or use the correct format. `Exportable` already does that

Comment: I will do a test so that the user only generates the xlsx and the result is published in this thread. Thanks for your help.

Comment: Forcing the file to be xlsx has worked without problems.